# Texture and Color mixing

Tags: node-editor

I need to mix 1 gray-white texture with yellow color.

Here is a model with a gray-white texture without the applied yellow color.
[image: without color]

I was able to apply a yellow color through the nodes, but it does not appear in the render.
[image: with color(not render)]

[image]

I need the same result, only to make the model yellow in the rendering.

please show me where I made a mistake =)

Comment: Try replacing the multiply shader with a mix shader

Comment: It's don't work

Comment: here is result
https://i.imgur.com/8i1wExb.png

Comment: Oh i done with this, using Principled BSDF.
https://i.imgur.com/HefBVtG.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix a color(or a texture) with a shader in Cycles. You are currently mixing a texture with a Diffuse BSDF shader - that's the problem. It will be enough to disconnect it and set the color directly in the MixRGB node to fix this.

If you wanted to have a separate node for the color for some reason(for example if you want to connect it to multiple inputs so you can change them all at once), you can use RGB node that you can find among Input nodes.